# Check whether Isolate is locked in V8

Tags: v8

In the V8 JavaScript engine, the method `Locker::IsLocked(Isolate* isolate)` checks "whether or not the locker for a given isolate, is locked by the current thread."

Is there a way to check whether an isolate is locked by *any* thread to prevent threads from blocking?

Comment: If the answer is "No", it is possible to use `boost::mutex`es, but checking the V8 API is much cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, V8 isolates don't provide a public `try_lock` operation, so you'll have to use `std::mutex` or something similar:

```
std::mutex mutex;
// ...
if (mutex.try_lock())
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex, std::adopt_lock);
    v8::Locker locker(isolate);
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately you'll have to follow this pattern everywhere you use the isolate. Good luck!